# Can we pronounce “can” as /kən/ at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: american-english, modal-verbs, pronunciation, vowels, word-stress

I know that “can” can be reduced to /kən/ unless it has to be stressed. For example in a sentence like “I believe I can fly” we can say /kən/ instead of /kæn/. My question is, can we do the same thing when “can” is at the beginning of an interrogative sentence as well? I mean can we say /kən/ in sentences like

- “Can I come in?”,
- “Can you sign my shirt?”

etc.

I tried to listen to some examples on Youglish, but I was not completely able to tell if they make the
schwa sound or not. I think we can do that since I think we don’t have to
stress “can” in the sentences like those two. Do you think we can? My
question is more specifically about American English.

Comment: This may depend on dialect and accent, but in my dialect (American English, New York), it's *always* /kən/, even if it's stressed.

Comment: Thanks stangdon. I would like to know why the disliker disliked my question.

Comment: @stangdon You mean it's always /kən/ in sentences like the ones I gave, right? I am guessing you would pronounce it as /kæn/ in a sentence like "Yes, I can!"

Comment: In some dialects of American English like mine, it's /kɛn/ when stressed, which confused me at first when I read your question.

Comment: The trouble, I always find, with using phonetic symbols is that when you look them up, you're given example words that **also** change pronunciation with accent. eg /æ/ as in bad, [clap](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/clap_1?q=clap). Both those words have a totally different a sound in US English than they do in UK. That leaves us with a starting point that's not a starting point. In my accent, N BrE, it's always kaen [using the British pronunciation guide] unless elided so far as to become kn.

Comment: @DanGetz Do you think it is okay to reduce it to the schwa sound in sentences like the ones I gave?

Comment: In what accent? I think that's the point several of us are making here. It's *never* a schwa in Br E, other than some extreme RP/posh instances, where it tends further towards ken than can.

Comment: @FireandIce I think so. I'm afraid to answer this question myself because I know my brain sometimes confuses /ɛ/ and /ə/.

Comment: Fire - have a look at this to see what a joke it becomes in the hands of guessers - https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/lesson-plans/phonetics-spelling-dictionary.html Look especially at the vowel section. A significan proportion of the examples they use don't even share the same sound. One is supposed to be a homonym… it's not.

Comment: @FireandIce - Nope, it's *always* pronounced "kən" in my accent (and, I think, most American accents).   Listen to [this video of Barack Obama](https://youtu.be/Fe751kMBwms?t=626) - his accent is a little different than mine, but he pronounces "Yes we can" much like I would.

Comment: @stangdon - that's not kən by any stretch of the imagination, it's kɛn, bordering on kæn [this is why phonetics don't work, they're based on a personal accent perception]

Comment: @FireandIce In BrE (SE England, Received Pronunciation, pretty much what I've been told I speak)  it is always pronounced /kæn/ no matter where it is in the sentence or the stress applied, unless it is elided , as gone fishn' again says to be just kn.

Comment: @PeterJennings - well, if you can get a Northerner & an RP speaker to agree on a pronunciation, that's got to be pretty much de facto standard for the UK ;)) [No doubt, there will be an accent difference, but we both perceive it as kæn, which is a darn good start]

Answer (score -1):

Because of the confusion in the comments, I'm going to avoid using phonetic transcriptions. Here are the two pronunciations (American English) that I will refer to:

1. Can as "ken" as in "Barbie and Ken." I will write this as "ken."
2. Can as in "can of soda." I will write this as "caan."

Both are correct to use at the beginning of a phrase. Yes, we can use the form "ken" even when "can" is at the beginning of an interrogative sentence?

"Can I come in?" could be pronounced "Ken I come in?"

"Can you sign my shirt?" could be pronounced "Ken you sign my shirt?"

"Ken" is used when you are talking to someone perhaps a bit informally, or talking quickly. "Caan" would be used more if it was a formal request.

To me, there is also an subtle expectation that you expect it to be an easy "yes" answer to the question if you pronounce "can" as "ken." That is, you are assuming that the person will probably let you come in or sign your shirt.

If it was something difficult for the person, or a major thing you are asking of them, then "caan" would be used.

> "Hello. Caan you take my place in the draft?"
>
> "I know you've had a busy week. I was wondering, caan you finish
> writing the article by Thursday?"

(While approaching a new office of a person in a different department that you haven't met:) "Caan I come in?"

[versus]

> "Hey dad, ken you drive me to the store in a bit?"
>
> (While wanting to enter somewhere you have entered before or suspect
> no reason why you may not enter:) "Ken I come in here?"

"Caan" can be used if you want to indicate that you are sincerely asking. "Ken" can be also used if you are sincerely asking, but it has less of the implication than "caan." In the two examples you gave, I would personally probably lean towards using "caan," but it depends on the context (whose room? who is signing the shirt and why?).